# Windows Terminal Adding git-bash always opens in new terminal window

Tags: git-bash, windows-terminal

I was able to figure out how to integrate Git-Bash in windows terminal, but when I select it, it always opens in a new window out side windows terminal. Profile bellow with names removed.

```
 {
    "tabTitle": "Git Bash",
    "acrylicOpacity": 0.5,
    "background": "#012456",
    "closeOnExit": true,
    "colorScheme": "Campbell",
    "commandline": "\"C:\\Program Files\\Git\\git-bash.exe\" --cd-to-home",
    "cursorColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "cursorShape": "bar",
    "fontFace": "Consolas",
    "fontSize": 10,
    "guid": "{<some guid>}",
    "historySize": 9001,
    "icon": "C:\\Users\\<user>\\Pictures\\gitbash.png",
    "name": "Git Bash",
    "padding": "0, 0, 0, 0",
    "snapOnInput": true,
    "startingDirectory": "C:\\Users\\<user>",
    "useAcrylic": true
  },
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it to work by changing the "commandline" to use bash.exe instead. 
Like:

```
{
  ...
  "commandline": "\"C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe\" --cd-to-home"
  ...
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between `bash.exe` and `git-bash.exe`? Do you lose any functionality using `bash.exe` instead of `git-bash.exe`?