# What's the difference between git-bash.exe and bash.exe and how they interact with Windows Terminal?

Tags: windows, bash, terminal, windows-terminal, git-bash

I've installed Git for Windows.

I want to run git-bash in a Windows Terminal tab.

I initially configured a git-bash profile, in Windows Terminal, whose `Command Line` field I populated with `C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe` because I noted that the `Git Bash` shortcut installed by the Git Bash installer pointed to that executable.

The result of this was that when I tried to open a new git-bash *tab*, Windows Terminal would open the git-bash shell in a new *window*. I would have preferred the shell to open in a new tab, not a new window.

Various posts on [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1468471/windows-terminal-adding-git-bash-always-opens-in-new-terminal-window) and [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61969007/git-bash-in-windows-terminal-is-opening-in-a-separate-window) describe people's annoyance with the described behavior, and the common workaround seems to be to change the `Command Line` field to `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe` instead of `C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe`, and this works in my case as well.

My question is **why** does using `C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe` result in the terminal being opened in a new window? Is there any functional difference between `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe` and `C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe`? Would I be losing anything by using the former instead of the latter?

I do no think this question is a dupe of the others because those Q&A do not discuss *why* this behavior is the way it is – they only mention the *how* of how to work around.

If there is a functional difference between `bash.exe` and `git-bash.exe`, is there any way to make `git-bash.exe` open in a new Windows Terminal *tab* instead of a new *window*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course they are different.

### git-bash.exe

`git-bash.exe` is a **terminal** executable based on mintty. I won't explain what terminal (and shell) is as the internet is full of materials about it (e.g. see this question: [What is the difference between shell, console, and terminal?](https://superuser.com/questions/144666/what-is-the-difference-between-shell-console-and-terminal)), I'll just shortly mention that this executable is basically aimed at providing a GUI window with options to the user. Hence a new window always opens when you launch it.

### bash.exe

`bash.exe` is a **shell** executable. Its main goal is to process/interpret the commands provided by the user. It can be hooked into any terminal that supports it, including **Windows Terminal**.

### Functional differences

Will you lose anything if you go for `bash.exe`? Well, you'll definitely not be able to use terminal preferences of Git Bash, if you set up any in its *Options..* menu:

[image: Options..]

You will also lose any GUI capabilities that the terminal provides and that Windows Terminal doesn't. But since Windows Terminal is a more modern terminal, I doubt there'll by anything relevant for most users.

Other than that, you won't lose any functionality.

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question, but I'm still curious why Windows Terminal launches `git-bash` in a new window, i.e. not a new tab, as noted in the question I linked in the OP. I _think_ that is not because of the difference between the executables being shells vs. terminals, because, e.g. `PowerShell` and `Command Prompt` are both terminals, not shells, yet Windows Terminal seems "willing" to launch them in new tabs.

Comment: `git-bash`, like other apps you mentioned, might also have any sort of switch that allows launching it as a shell, but since people are advising to use another executable instead, I doubt. It's simply coded to be UI only